# Laravel Backpack's CRUD data is not showing on custom operation form

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've been tinkering with Backpack for some moment and tried to create a custom operation called "Next Process". Basically, this operation is just an "edit" function with different fields to fill in (because we want the fields on the "create" function to be edited as well, and the filling of the "Next Process" will be done later after creating the data. So we don't want to just utilize the provided CRUD Edit trait).

The problem is, I am unable to show the value of the fields on this custom function's form. If we try to fill the form from scratch (with no existing data), The page works just fine. The value was stored and can be viewed on the "show" page. However, when we tried to go to the "Next Process" page again (now the field has been populated with some data), the existing data is not shown. Updating the form now resets all the existing data to empty, except for the field that we fill just now.

I have included the `$this->data['crud'] = $his->crud` and `$this->data['entry'] = $this->crud->getEntry($id)` at the beginning of the function, and passed the $data to the view. The view itself is just a published version of "edit" blade from Backpack's own template.

I have also tried to use the `$this->view->getEditCrud()` (just in case if the published template is the culprit), but the result is still the same.

What is wrong with this? I attach my code for reference.

```
public function getProcess($id)
      {
          $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('update');
          $this->crud->setOperation('process');
          $this->crud->setHeading('Process '.$this->crud->entity_name, 'getProcess'); // set the Heading for the create action
          $this->crud->setSubheading('Process '.$this->crud->entity_name, 'getProcess'); // set the Subheading for the create action
          $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = [
            trans('backpack::crud.admin') => backpack_url('dashboard'),
            $this->crud->entity_name_plural => url($this->crud->route),
            'Process '.$this->crud->entity_name => false
        ];
          // get the info for that entry
          $this->data['entry'] = $this->crud->getEntry($id);
          $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
          $this->data['title'] = 'Process '.$this->crud->entity_name;
          $this->data['id'] = $id;
          $this->crud->getEntry($id);

          $this->crud->addField([
              'name' => 'support_type',
              'label' => 'Support type',
          ]);

          // Redacted: Whole bunch of addField with the 'name' matching the database column's name 
          // (pretty sure it's not the problem since saving the form updates the specific field 
          // in the database).
          

        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'third_pty_partnership',
            'label' => 'Third Party Partnerships',
        ]);


        $this->data['saveAction'] = [
            "active" => [
                "value" => "save_and_back",
                "label" => "Save and go back"
            ],
            "options" => [

            ]
            ];

          return view('vendor.backpack.crud.processForm', $this->data);
      }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Put the addFields before the calls to the info for the entry.